# When the storage device is formatted with NTFS, the file tunneling system does not work

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, ntfs, format

Currently, I am experiencing a problem that some HDDs and SSDs formatted with NTFS do not have the file tunneling system working, so when I save files I have worked on to those disks, the creation date keeps changing to the saved date.

What's somewhat absurd is that when the USB is formatted as NTFS, the creation date of the file keeps changing to the date it was saved, as described above. However, if the USB is formatted as FAT32 or exFAT instead of NTFS, the creation date is preserved as it is when saving the file.

I am currently using Windows 10 and I am desperate for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you confirm… Your original & replacement files are in the same directory? Replacement time is under 15 seconds?

Comment: https://mcsi-library.readthedocs.io/articles/2022/05/windows-file-system-tunneling-in-digital-forensics/windows-file-system-tunneling-in-digital-forensics.html has the registry entires to adjust this

Comment: yes. The original and replacement files were in the same location and were saved within 15 seconds. However, the creation date is constantly changing.

Comment: I tried modifying the registry as per the referenced UPL address, but the problem still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: You do not need to put [solved] in the title. That's what we have the tick on the answer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article
[Windows File System Tunneling in Digital Forensics](https://mcsi-library.readthedocs.io/articles/2022/05/windows-file-system-tunneling-in-digital-forensics/windows-file-system-tunneling-in-digital-forensics.html)
explains the concepts and lists the two registry items that are
important for Tunneling.
Both are under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
as follows:

- `MaximumTunnelEntries` : Number of values can exist in the cache simultaneously, `0` disables tunneling.
- `MaximumTunnelEntryAgeInSeconds` : The lifetime of entries
  in the cache, default value is 15 seconds, maximum is 71 seconds.

**First action** : You should use regedit to verify these registry items
on your computer. The number of values might be too low or the lifetime
is too short for a long file-operation.

In the article
[I'll be back in 15 seconds. Or, maybe not. File system tunneling](https://unminioncurioso.blogspot.com/2020/07/ill-be-back-in-15-seconds-or-maybe-not.html),
the author has done very many tests of Tunneling, and has found this:

> Of the cases mentioned above, the only exception where the tunnel effect will not be generated is in the case of combining a long file name with its short name equivalent.

This means that referring to a file by both its long name and by its
short name (8.3) does not work. If the editing program you're using
does this inconsistent handling, then Tunneling will not work.

The author has also found this :

> Disabling the creation of short file names, (8.3), also disables the tunnelling of the file system, since tunnelling is based on such names.

Short file-names are discussed in the Microsoft article
[fsutil 8dot3name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name).

**Second action** : Run an elevated Command Prompt (CMD) and check
if short file names are enabled on the volume X: with the command:

```
fsutil 8dot3name query X:
```